# logarithms: $a^n =b$, got $\ln(x)$, but how do I get "$n$" using it?

Tags: logarithms

I learned a fast way to get $x$ in $\ln(x)$ using ($n= x-1$ btw)

$$\ln(x)=2\left(\frac{1}{2n+1}+\frac{1}{3(2n+1)^3}+\frac{1}{5(2n+1)^5}+\frac{1}{7(2n+1)^7}+\frac{1}{9(2n+1)^9}...\right)
$$

from wiki, which basically converts any base (i.e. $x$), like $2,$ into $e$ (base $2.71828..).$

But given something like $3^n=750$ or $2^n=1000,$ I still don't know how to get "n" by hand, and i don't understand how calculators are getting such high precision answers. $30$ decimals of precision must be coming from somewhere, and I think its math, because its too big to fit on a table, and since my computer doesn't crash or even blink when i get an answer, the number of steps can't possibly be in the millions, or likely even the thousands.

What's going on? How do I get $n,$ once I have $\ln(x)$ solved?

Comment: I don't understand what you are asking.  Do you want to solve $3^n=750$ for $n?$

Comment: It's really not clear what you're asking. If you're asking how do computers calculate logarithms, there are lots of good methods, all numerical. For example, if you look at your series above, it converges quite rapidly; using just the terms you have shown, if $n=2$ you already get eight digits of precision.

Comment: By the way, don't you mean $$n={x-1\over1+x}?$$

Answer (score 0):

If you want to perform a change of basis, from base $a$ to $e$. Where $a>0$.
$$\log_ax = \frac{\ln(x)}{\ln(a)}$$ And using your expansion this should work. Where in your examples $a=2$ or $a=3$